# Hebrew bedtime shma text online

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, internet, sleep, shema

I am trying to find an online hebrew copy of shma bmita that includes the introductory paragraph, hareini mohel l'chol, that I can copy and print for my own research.

I appreciate any suggestions anyone has. (I couldn't find this paragraph on the Hebrew wiki or online siddur.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:  http://www.tefillos.com/krias_shema.asp

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21127&st=&pgnum=489), [this](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47846&st=&pgnum=317), [this](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49762&st=&pgnum=550), or [this](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16091&st=&pgnum=296).